# Openpyxl to check for keywords, then modify next to cells to contain those keywords and total found

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using python 3.x and openpyxl to parse an excel .xlsx file.

For each row, I check a column (C) to see if any of those keywords match.
If so, I add them to a separate list variable and also determine how many keywords were matched.

I then want to add the actual keywords into the next cell, and the total of keywords into the cell after. This is where I am having trouble, actually writing the results.

contents of the keywords.txt and results.xlsx file 
[here](http://pastebin.com/nLtzsFYj)

```
import openpyxl

# Here I read a keywords.txt file and input them into a keywords variable 
# I throwaway the first line to prevent a mismatch due to the unicode BOM
with open("keywords.txt") as f:
    f.readline()
    keywords = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f]

# Load the workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("results.xlsx")
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet")

# Iterate through every row, only looking in column C for the keyword match.
for row in ws.iter_rows("C{}:E{}".format(ws.min_row, ws.max_row)):
    # if there's a match, add to the keywords_found list
    keywords_found = [key for key in keywords if key in row[0].value]
    # if any keywords found, enter the keywords in column D
    # and how many keywords into column E
    if len(keywords_found):
        row[1].value = keywords_found
        row[2].value = len(keywords_found)
```

Now, I understand **where** I'm going wrong, in that ws.iter_rows(..) returns a tuple, which can't be modified. I figure I could two for loops, one for each row, and another for the columns in each row, but this test is a small example of a real-world scenario, where the amount of rows are in the tens of thousands.

I'm not quite sure which is the best way to go about this. Thankyou in advance for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ws['C']` and then the `offset()` method of the relevant cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Charlie for the `offset()` tip. I modified the code slightly and now it works a treat.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows("C{}:C{}"...)
    for cell in row:
    ....
    if len(keywords_found):
        cell.offset(0,1).value = str(keywords_found)
        cell.offset(0,2).value = str(len(keywords_found))
```